# Getting the SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor

Tags: .net, sql, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to get the Sync New Received Anchor to be stored in my Server Side database. The Purpose is to store the Time Stamp in which we have received the data from the client. To achieve this we are using the following command:

```
    SqlCommand selectNewAnchorCommand = new SqlCommand();
    string newAnchorVariable = "@" + SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor;
    selectNewAnchorCommand.CommandText = "SELECT " + newAnchorVariable + " = GETUTCDATE()";
    selectNewAnchorCommand.Parameters.Add(newAnchorVariable, SqlDbType.DateTime);
    selectNewAnchorCommand.Parameters[newAnchorVariable].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    selectNewAnchorCommand.Connection = serverConnection;
    this.serverProvider.SelectNewAnchorCommand = selectNewAnchorCommand;
```

and once we receive th Anchor i am using it in the following way:

sqlCmdTransactionMaster.Parameters.Add("@" + SyncSession.SyncNewReceivedAnchor, SqlDbType.DateTime);
The Output should be "Current Date" but i am getting the following date

"1753-01-01 12:00:00.000"

This date is a default date available in SQL Server.

Environment :  Visual Studio 2008 , Sync Framework 2.1 & SQL Server 2008 (with Tracking False)

The Purpose of this whole exercise is to get the Server date in the table when the record is inserted in the server. Is there any other way of getting that done?

Please let me know where i am going wrong in this:

Thanks in Advance
Biju Melayil

Comment: You should probably use a trigger for that. It seems like a very long way to do what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks Leppie. I have added the Trigger. But what is the right way of getting the New Anchor? The Samples available in Microsoft Site shows TimeStamp which doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would normally do this with change tracking enabled and by using the change tracking function CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933945.aspx

This example explains a lot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx

But maybe enabling change tracking is not an option for you?